# how to find intersection points when lines are created from an array

Tags: matlab, math, octave, linear-algebra

**The intersections functioned recommended below worked great for arrays up to 8000 values but if I had an array of 100000 values or more I would run out of memory, (and I have 16gig of ram) this most likely was caused due to the repmat command with the intersections function.**

I'm trying to find the intersection points of lines created from an array.  but keep getting an error "**fzero: not a valid initial bracketing**"  I'm using **octave 3.8.1** (which is an open source version of matlab)  The image below is what I'm trying to get with the black circles at the intersection points.
Do I need to have the fzero in a for loop to loop through the array of x and y values?

```
clear all,clf, clc,tic

%freq array here
x1=[20,30,40,50,60,70,80]';
x2=[20,30,40,50,60,70,80]';
y1=[2,4,3,7,1,8,4]';
y2=abs(y1-max(y1)); %used to switch high and low amplitude of freq

%fit linear polynomial
p1 = polyfit(x1,y1,1);
p2 = polyfit(x2,y2,1);  

%calculate intersection
x_intersect = fzero(@(x) polyval(p1-p2,x),3);
y_intersect = polyval(p1,x_intersect);

line(x1,y1);
hold on;
line(x2,y2);
plot(x_intersect,y_intersect,'r*')
```

**The intersections functioned recommended below worked great for arrays up to 8000 values but if I had an array of 100000 values or more I would run out of memory, (and I have 16gig of ram) this most likely was caused due to the repmat command with the intersections function.**

```
So now I'm trying to:
1) cycle though each row in the array which represents a line 

linea1-6 xvalues = 20 to 30, 30 to 40, 40 to 50, 50 to 60, 60 to 70, 70 to 80
linea1-6 yvalues =2 to 4, 4 to 3, 3 to 7, 7 to 1, 1 to 8, 8 to 4
lineb1-6 xvalues = 20 to 30, 30 to 40, 40 to 50, 50 to 60, 60 to 70, 70 to 80
lineb1-6 yvalues =6 to 4, 4 to 5, 5 to 1, 1 to 7, 7 to 0, 0 to 4

**I'm having problems coding the for loop to work with polyfit and fzero**


2) store the intersection values found for each line into an array.
This should solve running out of memory issues when using large arrays
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you are using; however, you do have single quote at the end of your lines declaring x1, x2, and y1.  Perhaps that is related to your problem?

Comment: @Ander Biguri No it's not a duplicate please read updated question the original answer will not work for large arrays.

Comment: I think it would help if you could better describe your input data. Is X2 always equal to x1 and are they equally spaced and monotonic? Is y2=abs(y1-max(y1)) only in your example. If we can make those assumptions this would greatly simplify the calculations. No need for fzero or polyval in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not using the solution given to your previous question [Finding where plots may cross with octave / matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984168/finding-where-plots-may-cross-with-octave-matlab)

But here's what's happening here (from the doc):

> If `X0` is a single scalar then several nearby and distant values are
>   probed in an attempt to obtain a valid bracketing.  If this is not
>   successful, the function fails.

So what's happening is that your initial guess of `3` is too far away from the solution. Try that instead:

```
>> x_intersect = fzero(@(x) polyval(p1-p2,x),30)
x_intersect =  46.667
```

However, I am not sure what you are trying to do by fitting a first degree polynomial to your data, it doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: The intersections functioned recommended below worked great for arrays up to 8000 values but if I had an array of 100000 values or more I would run out of memory, (and I have 16gig of ram) this most likely was caused due to the repmat command with the intersections function.

So now I'm trying to:
1) cycle though each row in the array which represents a line 
2) store the intersection value in an array.
This should solve running out of memory issues using large arrays