# Matlab : Intersect point of curves

Tags: matlab, curve, intersect

Say for example I have data which forms the parabolic curve y=x^2, and I want to read off the x value for a given y value. How do I go about doing this in MATLAB?

If it were a straight line, I could just use the equation of the line of best fit to calculate easily, however I can't do this with a curved line. If I can't find a solution, I'll solve for roots

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why can't you do the same for a parabolic curve as for a line? Your data forms a parabolic curve anyway so it's a good fit....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all data are arrays (not analytical expressions), I usually do that finding minimal absolute error

```
x=some_array;
[~,ind]=min(abs(x.^2-y0))
```

Here `y0` is a given y value

If your data are represented by a function, you can use `fsolve`:

```
function y = myfun(x)
    y=x^2-y0

[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options)
```

For symbolic computations, one can use `solve`

```
syms x
solve(x^2 - y0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your two curves are just two vectors of data, I would suggest you use [Fast and Robust Curve Intersections](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections) from the File Exchange. See also these two similar questions: [how to find intersection points when lines are created from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062191/how-to-find-intersection-points-when-lines-are-created-from-an-array/) and [Finding where plots may cross with octave / matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984168/finding-where-plots-may-cross-with-octave-matlab).